# After mandatory field validations, need to check passwords are same in 'keyup' event Bootstrap 5 but css are not set back to red

Tags: javascript, validation, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Code

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
        .forEach(function (form) {
        var passwordInput = form.querySelector('#password');
        var confirmPasswordInput = form.querySelector('#confirm-password');
        var confirmPasswordFeedback = form.querySelector('.confirm-password-feedback')
        passwordInput.addEventListener('keyup', validatePasswords);
        confirmPasswordInput.addEventListener('keyup', validatePasswords);
        function validatePasswords() {
            const confirmDefaultDiv = document.querySelector('.confirm-password-default');
            if (confirmDefaultDiv) {    
                confirmDefaultDiv.style.display = 'none';
            }              
            if (passwordInput.value === confirmPasswordInput.value) {   
                confirmPasswordInput.classList.remove('is-invalid');
                confirmPasswordInput.classList.add('is-valid');
                confirmPasswordFeedback.textContent = ''; // Clear error message              
            } else {
                confirmPasswordInput.classList.remove('is-valid');
                confirmPasswordInput.classList.add('is-invalid');
                confirmPasswordFeedback.textContent = "Passwords do not match"; // Set error message
            }
        }
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            if (!form.checkValidity() || passwordInput.value !== confirmPasswordInput.value) {
            event.preventDefault()
            event.stopPropagation()
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
            //form.classList.remove('was-validated')
        }, false)
        })
})()
```

### ***Issue***

After mandatory field validations, compare if the user's entered passwords are the same using the **keyup** event. Although the error message is visible, the textbox is always displayed in green, as shown below. This should only change to green when the correct passwords match.
As per my understanding, this is happening due to .was-validated class, which is in . I can't reset the form. Is there any solution to fix this problem? Also, please note that as an initial step, entering passwords works as expected.

[image]

Highly appreciate the support!
Thanks !